# Why lodash automatically split into vendor in webpack?

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack with react. When import lodash in one screen, I am confused to see there is a vendor bundle file **/js/vendors-node_modules_lodash_lodash_js.3715c9aa.js**.I do not config the **SplitChunksPlugin** option.

My webpack config file

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/i,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "index.html"
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
        host: "localhost",
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    }
};
```